# Почему span не реагирует на text-align?

Tags: html, css

Хотелось бы понять, почему тег `span` [не реагирует](http://jsfiddle.net/BFQJ4/) на свойство `text-align`:

```html
<span style="text-align: right !important">123</span>
```

Нужно что-то придумать, главное **не** `div` или `p`. Хотя можно было и `float`, но ведь для него, вроде как, `center` нет.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Сурово... ну сделайте так, если вам очень нужен span

```
display: block;
text-align: right;
```

Comment: @psyсho_Octopus, я наоборот использую span, чтобы не было переносов в таких случаях http://jsfiddle.net/BFQJ4/2/, а Вы тут display: block предлагаете :(

Comment: Ссылка битая, а вообще какой вопрос, такой и ответ.

Comment: Исправил, просто запятая попала под расчёт )

Comment: Это уже совсем другая задача. Для ее решения можете использовать float:right/left, например

Answer (score 4):

http://jsfiddle.net/ZondArt/BFQJ4/1/

Span - это строчный элемент и его ширина = его содержимому, поэтому хоть center, хоть right — изменений видно не будет.

Comment: @ZondArt, я наоборот использую span, чтобы не было переносов в таких случаях http://jsfiddle.net/BFQJ4/2/, а Вы тут display: block предлагаете :(

Answer (score 2):

Display: inline-block; width: 500px; text-align: center

Answer (score 0):

Нужно родителю задать `text-align: center;` и тогда span выровняется по центру.

```
<div style="text-align:center;">
<span>kkk</span>
</div>
```